# reg problems:TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am trying the code:

```
`s='{"mail":vip@a.com,"type":"a","r_id":"1312","level":307},{"mail":vipx@a.com,"type":"b","r_id":"1111"}'`
data_raw=re.split(r'[\{\}]',s)
data_raw=data_raw[1::2]
data=pd.DataFrame(data_raw)
data[0]=str(data[0])
data['r_id']=data[0].apply(lambda x:re.search(r'(r_id)',data[0]))
data['level']=data[0].apply(lambda x:re.search(r'(level)',data[0]))
print(data)
```

I wish I could get the result:

r_id  level

1312  307

1111 NAN

But it shows the error:expected string or bytes-like object
So how could I use the re.search in pandas or how could I get result?

Comment: Please update your question with the full Traceback of the error.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents...

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'^.*?id\":\"(\d+)\",\"level\":(\d+).*id\":\"(\d+).*$')

string = r'{"mail":vip@a.com,"type":"a","r_id":"1312","level":307},{"mail":vipx@a.com,"type":"b","r_id":"1111"}'

data = pattern.findall(string)

data
```

Which returns an array:

```
[('1312', '307', '1111')]
```

And you can access items with, for example:

```
data[0][2]
```

Regex demo: https://regex101.com/r/Inv4gp/1

Answer (score 0):

The below works for me. The type problem arises because you cannot change the type of all the rows like that. You would need a lambda functor for that too.

There is an additional problem, that the regex and the exception case handling won't work like that. I proposed a solution for this, but you might want to consider a different regex if you want this to work for other columns.
I'm very novice with regex, so there might be a more general-purpose solution for your problem.

```
import re
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s='{"mail":vip@a.com,"type":"a","r_id":"1312","level":307},{"mail":vipx@a.com,"type":"b","r_id":"1111"}'
data_raw=re.split(r'[\{\}]',s)
data_raw=data_raw[1::2]
data=pd.DataFrame(data_raw)



# This is a regex wrapper which gets the row of our pandas dataframes and the columns that we want.
def regex_wrapper(row,column):
    match = re.search(r'"' + column + '":"?(\d+)"?', str(row))
    if match:
        return match.group(1)
    else:
        return np.nan


data['r_id'] = data[0].apply(lambda row: regex_wrapper(row,"r_id"))
data['level'] = data[0].apply(lambda row: regex_wrapper(row,"level"))
del data[0]
```